# how to handle data inside grid system in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am creating a webpage in bootstrap using the grid system but having issues with the columns data. The containers are responsive but the data inside is not. How do I solve this issue. Please tell me what I am missing and what problem is it ... 
Thanks alot

**on desktop view**

[image]

**in mobile view**

[image]

Here is my all code...

```css
/* CSS Document */
/*background--start-*/

body {
    background: url(images/drinks.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
/*background--end-*/
/*Logo-- start--*/

.hit-the-floor {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 6em;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: ruthie;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc, 0 2px 0 #c9c9c9, 0 3px 0 #bbb, 0 4px 0 #b9b9b9, 0 5px 0 #aaa, 0 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}
.hit-the-floor {
    text-align: center;
}
.hit-the-floor1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 4em;
    margin-left: 300px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: ruthie;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc, 0 2px 0 #c9c9c9, 0 3px 0 #bbb, 0 4px 0 #b9b9b9, 0 5px 0 #aaa, 0 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}
.hit-the-floor1 {
    text-align: center;
}
/*Logo--End--*/
/*navbar start*/

.nav_custom {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 950px;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav > li {
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: #000000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 130px;
}
/*navbar end*/
/*location  start*/

#b {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.location {
    width: 87%;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #C1BEBE;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
/*Location end*/

.boddy {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
}
/* Left Side bar*/

.left-sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 800px;
    position: fixed;
}
/* Base Styles */

#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
}
#cssmenu a {
    line-height: 1.3;
}
#cssmenu {
    width: 200px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    padding-right: 40px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    background: #03FE91;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #5e071b;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a > span {
    background: #26C17E;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active {
    border-bottom: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
    color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a span {
    background: #26C17E;
}
#cssmenu span.cnt {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 15px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: none;
}
/* Sub menu */

#cssmenu ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-top: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
    color: #26C17E;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.odd {
    background: #f4f4f4;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.even {
    background: #fff;
}
/*end left side bar*/

.MainArea {
    width: 1148px;
    height: 800px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
/* search  start */

.search {
    width: 87%;
    height: 55px;
    background-color: #8F8B8B;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -400px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop:before {
    background: #444;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #151515, #444, #151515);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #151515, #444, #151515);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #151515, #444, #151515);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #151515, #444, #151515);
    background: linear-gradient(left, #151515, #444, #151515);
    top: 192px;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop:after {
    background: #000;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #151515, #000, #151515);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #151515, #000, #151515);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #151515, #000, #151515);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #151515, #000, #151515);
    background: linear-gradient(left, #151515, #000, #151515);
    top: 191px;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop form {
    background: #111;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1b1b1b, #111);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#1b1b1b, #111);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#1b1b1b, #111);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#1b1b1b, #111);
    background: linear-gradient(#1b1b1b, #111);
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #272727;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0px;
    margin: 150px auto 0;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop input {
    background: #222;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    background: linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    border: 1px solid #444;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #000;
    color: #888;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Cabin', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 42px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
    width: 200px;
}
#ie #webdesigntuts-workshop input {
    line-height: 40px;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #888;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #888;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop input:focus {
    -webkit-animation: glow 800ms ease-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: glow 800ms ease-out infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: glow 800ms ease-out infinite alternate;
    -ms-animation: glow 800ms ease-out infinite alternate;
    animation: glow 800ms ease-out infinite alternate;
    background: #222922;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#333933, #222922);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#333933, #222922);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#333933, #222922);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#333933, #222922);
    background: linear-gradient(#333933, #222922);
    border-color: #393;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, .2), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, .1), 0 2px 0 #000;
    color: #efe;
    outline: none;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #efe;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop input:focus:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #efe;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop button {
    background: #222;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    background: linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -o-box-sizing: content-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    border-left-color: #000;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #000;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Cabin', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
    width: 80px;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop button:hover,
#webdesigntuts-workshop button:focus {
    background: #292929;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    background: linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    color: #5f5;
    outline: none;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop button:active {
    background: #292929;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    background: linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000, inset 1px 0 1px #222;
    top: 1px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes glow {
    0% {
        border-color: #393;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, .2), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, .1), 0 2px 0 #000;
    }
    100% {
        border-color: #6f6;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 255, 0, .6), inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 255, 0, .4), 0 2px 0 #000;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes glow {
    0% {
        border-color: #393;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, .2), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, .1), 0 2px 0 #000;
    }
    100% {
        border-color: #6f6;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 255, 0, .6), inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 255, 0, .4), 0 2px 0 #000;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes glow {
    0% {
        border-color: #393;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, .2), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, .1), 0 2px 0 #000;
    }
    100% {
        border-color: #6f6;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 255, 0, .6), inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 255, 0, .4), 0 2px 0 #000;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes glow {
    0% {
        border-color: #393;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, .2), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, .1), 0 2px 0 #000;
    }
    100% {
        border-color: #6f6;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 255, 0, .6), inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 255, 0, .4), 0 2px 0 #000;
    }
}
@keyframes glow {
    0% {
        border-color: #393;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, .2), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, .1), 0 2px 0 #000;
    }
    100% {
        border-color: #6f6;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 255, 0, .6), inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 255, 0, .4), 0 2px 0 #000;
    }
}
/*search end*/

.item-data {
    width: 942px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #000000;
}
.item {
    width: 942px;
    height: 140px;
    background-color: #4B3939;
    border-bottom: #FFFFFF 1px solid;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.image-size {
    background: url(images/jalal.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 120px;
    height: 95px;
    border: #FFFFFF 1px solid;
    box-shadow: #000000;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.text {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000000;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-top: -95px;
}
.text1 {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
    margin-left: 150px;
}
.rate_bar {
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: 400px;
    margin-top: -55px;
}
article {
    width: 60%;
    height: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.p2 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.circle-area {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: static;
    margin-top: 150px;
}
.myimg {
    margin-top: 15px;
    opacity: 1;
}
.circle {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 75px;
    margin-left: 170px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.circle:hover {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 75px;
}
.small {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #2F9615;
    border-radius: 60px;
}
.small:hover {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    transform: scale(1);
    background-color: #2F9615;
    border-radius: 75px;
}
footer {
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-top: 27px;
    opacity: .6;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
}
p {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: 2px;
}
.p1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>deals</title>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- sidebar script-->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12" >
          <p class="hit-the-floor">Restaurant</p>
          <p class="hit-the-floor1">Hunt</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

          <div class="nav_custom">
            <nav class="navbar" >
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header form-group">
                  <select class="navbar-toggle collapsed selectpicker 
                                 form-control"   data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hafiz" 
                          style="background: #ffffff; color:#000000;">
                    <option value="">Go to...</option>
                    <option value="#">Home</option>
                    <option value="#">Menu</option>
                    <option value="#">Restaurant</option>
                    <option value="#">About</option>
                  </select>    
                </div>
                <div class=" collapse navbar-collapse" id="hafiz">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

          <div class="location" >
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6" align="">

                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/location.png" alt="location"  
                     width="40px" height="40px"  />
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <button id="b"  type="button" class="btn btn-success">Change location
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="search">
            <form  id="webdesigntuts-workshop" action="" method="">
              <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." ><button> Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <div class="left-sidebar">
            <div id="cssmenu">
              <ul>
                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Deals Filter</span></a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>All Deals (7)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Kids Deals (1)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Hyper Discount (2)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Lunch Deals (1)</span></a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Midnight Deals (1)</span></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Cuisines</span></a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Bakery (1)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>BBQ (1)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Chinese(1)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Continental (2)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Mediterranean (1)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Italian (1)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Pakistani (3)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Pizza (7)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Frozen Yogurt (Froyo) (1)</span></a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Fast Food (11)</span></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="has-sub last"><a href="#"><span>Buduge</span></a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>About</span></a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Location</span></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">

          <div class="item-data">
            <div class="item">
              <div  class="image-size">
                <img  src="images/strip-sponsored.png" alt="img">
              </div>
              <p class="text">Jalal Sons, Allama Iqbal Twon</p>
              <p class="text1">Bakery, Fast Food, Frozen Yogurt (Froyo)</p>
              <div class="rate_bar">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div  class="image-size">
                <img  src="images/strip-sponsored.png" alt="img">
              </div>
              <p class="text">Jalal Sons, Allama Iqbal Twon</p>
              <p class="text1">Bakery, Fast Food, Frozen Yogurt (Froyo)</p>
              <div class="rate_bar">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div  class="image-size">
                <img  src="images/strip-sponsored.png" alt="img">
              </div>
              <p class="text">Jalal Sons, Allama Iqbal Twon</p>
              <p class="text1">Bakery, Fast Food, Frozen Yogurt (Froyo)</p>
              <div class="rate_bar">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div  class="image-size">
                <img  src="images/strip-sponsored.png" alt="img">
              </div>
              <p class="text">Jalal Sons, Allama Iqbal Twon</p>
              <p class="text1">Bakery, Fast Food, Frozen Yogurt (Froyo)</p>
              <div class="rate_bar">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div  class="image-size">
                <img  src="images/strip-sponsored.png" alt="img">
              </div>
              <p class="text">Jalal Sons, Allama Iqbal Twon</p>
              <p class="text1">Bakery, Fast Food, Frozen Yogurt (Froyo)</p>
              <div class="rate_bar">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have just set a behavior to big screens (`col-lg-12`); if you want a different arrangement on small screens, set `col-xs` values aswell. Bootstrap isn't magic, it does part of the work for you, not all the work.

Comment: There is a lot more here to fix rather than just changing lg to sm.

Comment: i am new in this technology kindly show me how to do that whats steps i have to follow  i am very thankfull to you

Answer (score 0):

Made some small changes into your code, you should check the bootstrap documentation for further informations. http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html
Also check the changes in your divs & documentation about bootstrap `table-responsive` (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables)

When you want your page to be responsive, try not to fix items for instance `width: 942px` becomes `max-width: 942px`

```css
/* CSS Document */
/*background--start-*/

body {
    background: url(images/drinks.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
/*background--end-*/
/*Logo-- start--*/

.hit-the-floor {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 6em;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: ruthie;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc, 0 2px 0 #c9c9c9, 0 3px 0 #bbb, 0 4px 0 #b9b9b9, 0 5px 0 #aaa, 0 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}
.hit-the-floor {
    text-align: center;
}
.hit-the-floor1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 4em;
    margin-left: 300px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: ruthie;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc, 0 2px 0 #c9c9c9, 0 3px 0 #bbb, 0 4px 0 #b9b9b9, 0 5px 0 #aaa, 0 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}
.hit-the-floor1 {
    text-align: center;
}
/*Logo--End--*/
/*navbar start*/

.nav_custom {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 950px;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav > li {
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: #000000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 130px;
}
/*navbar end*/
/*location  start*/

#b {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.location {
    width: 87%;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #C1BEBE;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
/*Location end*/

.boddy {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
}
/* Left Side bar*/

.left-sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 800px;
    position: fixed;
}
/* Base Styles */

#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
}
#cssmenu a {
    line-height: 1.3;
}
#cssmenu {
    width: 200px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    padding-right: 40px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    background: #03FE91;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #5e071b;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a > span {
    background: #26C17E;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active {
    border-bottom: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
    color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a span {
    background: #26C17E;
}
#cssmenu span.cnt {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 15px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: none;
}
/* Sub menu */

#cssmenu ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-top: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
    color: #26C17E;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.odd {
    background: #f4f4f4;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.even {
    background: #fff;
}
/*end left side bar*/

.MainArea {
    width: 1148px;
    height: 800px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
/* search  start */

.search {
    width: 87%;
    height: 55px;
    background-color: #8F8B8B;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -400px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop:before {
    background: #444;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #151515, #444, #151515);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #151515, #444, #151515);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #151515, #444, #151515);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #151515, #444, #151515);
    background: linear-gradient(left, #151515, #444, #151515);
    top: 192px;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop:after {
    background: #000;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #151515, #000, #151515);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #151515, #000, #151515);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #151515, #000, #151515);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #151515, #000, #151515);
    background: linear-gradient(left, #151515, #000, #151515);
    top: 191px;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop form {
    background: #111;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1b1b1b, #111);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#1b1b1b, #111);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#1b1b1b, #111);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#1b1b1b, #111);
    background: linear-gradient(#1b1b1b, #111);
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #272727;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0px;
    margin: 150px auto 0;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop input {
    background: #222;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    background: linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    border: 1px solid #444;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #000;
    color: #888;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Cabin', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 42px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
    width: 200px;
}
#ie #webdesigntuts-workshop input {
    line-height: 40px;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #888;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #888;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop input:focus {
    -webkit-animation: glow 800ms ease-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: glow 800ms ease-out infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: glow 800ms ease-out infinite alternate;
    -ms-animation: glow 800ms ease-out infinite alternate;
    animation: glow 800ms ease-out infinite alternate;
    background: #222922;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#333933, #222922);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#333933, #222922);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#333933, #222922);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#333933, #222922);
    background: linear-gradient(#333933, #222922);
    border-color: #393;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, .2), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, .1), 0 2px 0 #000;
    color: #efe;
    outline: none;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #efe;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop input:focus:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #efe;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop button {
    background: #222;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    background: linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -o-box-sizing: content-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    border-left-color: #000;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #000;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Cabin', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
    width: 80px;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop button:hover,
#webdesigntuts-workshop button:focus {
    background: #292929;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    background: linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    color: #5f5;
    outline: none;
}
#webdesigntuts-workshop button:active {
    background: #292929;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    background: linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000, inset 1px 0 1px #222;
    top: 1px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes glow {
    0% {
        border-color: #393;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, .2), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, .1), 0 2px 0 #000;
    }
    100% {
        border-color: #6f6;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 255, 0, .6), inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 255, 0, .4), 0 2px 0 #000;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes glow {
    0% {
        border-color: #393;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, .2), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, .1), 0 2px 0 #000;
    }
    100% {
        border-color: #6f6;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 255, 0, .6), inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 255, 0, .4), 0 2px 0 #000;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes glow {
    0% {
        border-color: #393;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, .2), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, .1), 0 2px 0 #000;
    }
    100% {
        border-color: #6f6;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 255, 0, .6), inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 255, 0, .4), 0 2px 0 #000;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes glow {
    0% {
        border-color: #393;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, .2), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, .1), 0 2px 0 #000;
    }
    100% {
        border-color: #6f6;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 255, 0, .6), inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 255, 0, .4), 0 2px 0 #000;
    }
}
@keyframes glow {
    0% {
        border-color: #393;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, .2), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, .1), 0 2px 0 #000;
    }
    100% {
        border-color: #6f6;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 255, 0, .6), inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 255, 0, .4), 0 2px 0 #000;
    }
}
/*search end*/

.item-data {
    width: 942px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #000000;
}
.item {
    max-width: 942px;
    height: 140px;
    background-color: #4B3939;
    border-bottom: #FFFFFF 1px solid;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.image-size {
    background: url(images/jalal.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 120px;
    height: 95px;
    border: #FFFFFF 1px solid;
    box-shadow: #000000;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.text {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000000;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-top: -95px;
}
.text1 {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
    margin-left: 150px;
}
.rate_bar {
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    float:right;
    position: relative;
}
article {
    width: 60%;
    height: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.p2 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.circle-area {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: static;
    margin-top: 150px;
}
.myimg {
    margin-top: 15px;
    opacity: 1;
}
.circle {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 75px;
    margin-left: 170px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.circle:hover {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 75px;
}
.small {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #2F9615;
    border-radius: 60px;
}
.small:hover {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    transform: scale(1);
    background-color: #2F9615;
    border-radius: 75px;
}
footer {
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-top: 27px;
    opacity: .6;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
}
p {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: 2px;
}
.p1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>deals</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- sidebar script-->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12" >
          <p class="hit-the-floor">Restaurant</p>
          <p class="hit-the-floor1">Hunt</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

          <div class="nav_custom">
            <nav class="navbar" >
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header form-group">
                  <select class="navbar-toggle collapsed selectpicker 
                                 form-control"   data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hafiz" 
                          style="background: #ffffff; color:#000000;">
                    <option value="">Go to...</option>
                    <option value="#">Home</option>
                    <option value="#">Menu</option>
                    <option value="#">Restaurant</option>
                    <option value="#">About</option>
                  </select>    
                </div>
                <div class=" collapse navbar-collapse" id="hafiz">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

          <div class="location" >
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6" align="">

                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/location.png" alt="location"  
                     width="40px" height="40px"  />
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <button id="b"  type="button" class="btn btn-success">Change location
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="search">
            <form  id="webdesigntuts-workshop" action="" method="">
              <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." ><button> Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <div class="left-sidebar">
            <div id="cssmenu">
              <ul>
                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Deals Filter</span></a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>All Deals (7)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Kids Deals (1)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Hyper Discount (2)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Lunch Deals (1)</span></a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Midnight Deals (1)</span></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Cuisines</span></a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Bakery (1)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>BBQ (1)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Chinese(1)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Continental (2)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Mediterranean (1)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Italian (1)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Pakistani (3)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Pizza (7)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Frozen Yogurt (Froyo) (1)</span></a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Fast Food (11)</span></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="has-sub last"><a href="#"><span>Buduge</span></a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>About</span></a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Location</span></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>


          <div class="table-responsive">
            <div class="item">
              <div  class="image-size">
                <img  src="images/strip-sponsored.png" alt="img">
              </div>
              <p class="text">Jalal Sons, Allama Iqbal Twon</p>
              <p class="text1">Bakery, Fast Food, Frozen Yogurt (Froyo)</p>
              <div class="rate_bar">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div  class="image-size">
                <img  src="images/strip-sponsored.png" alt="img">
              </div>
              <p class="text">Jalal Sons, Allama Iqbal Twon</p>
              <p class="text1">Bakery, Fast Food, Frozen Yogurt (Froyo)</p>
              <div class="rate_bar">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div  class="image-size">
                <img  src="images/strip-sponsored.png" alt="img">
              </div>
              <p class="text">Jalal Sons, Allama Iqbal Twon</p>
              <p class="text1">Bakery, Fast Food, Frozen Yogurt (Froyo)</p>
              <div class="rate_bar">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div  class="image-size">
                <img  src="images/strip-sponsored.png" alt="img">
              </div>
              <p class="text">Jalal Sons, Allama Iqbal Twon</p>
              <p class="text1">Bakery, Fast Food, Frozen Yogurt (Froyo)</p>
              <div class="rate_bar">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div  class="image-size">
                <img  src="images/strip-sponsored.png" alt="img">
              </div>
              <p class="text">Jalal Sons, Allama Iqbal Twon</p>
              <p class="text1">Bakery, Fast Food, Frozen Yogurt (Froyo)</p>
              <div class="rate_bar">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

      </div> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks alot i will read this documentation now and make it better :)